# Python While-loop Not Working Properly

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
def pressC():
    """ Wait for "c" to be entered from the keyboard in the Python shell """
    entry = " "
    while(entry != "c"):
        entry = raw_input("Press c to continue. ")
    print("Thank you. ")
    print

def unstuck():
    """ This gets the robot unstuck if it becomes stalled by hitting a wall   """
    stalls = 0
    while timeRemaining(120):
        stallStatus = getStall()
        if(stallStatus == 1):
            backward(1,1)
            turnRight(1,1.7145)
            stalls = stalls + 1
            return stalls
        else:
            forward(1,1)
    stop()

def printResults(stalls):
    """ This function prints the amount of times the robot stalled """
    print
    print ("The amount of stalls that occured: " + str(stalls) + ". ")

def main():
    pressC()
    numStalls = unstuck()
    printResults(numStalls)

main()
```

So, I am running the code on the myro simulator and the user-defined unstuck() function only runs once, and then prints that the robot only stalled once. The first while-loop runs properly, but the second one does not. Anyways, I want it to run for the 120 seconds I inputted. I need help!

Comment: `while` isn't a function, and I'll happily bet it's working just fine.

Comment: Please make sure you copy your indentation correctly when posting Python code. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: Sorry about that, but it is not. I believe it has something to do with the results printed. I deleted that portion and the while-loop works properly, so I believe it has something to do with my coding in that area.

Comment: Please provide a short, complete example demonstrating the problem. That way, others can reproduce your issue without guessing what your missing functions do. As an added benefit, in the process of reducing your code to a complete example, you might discover the solution yourself. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: @DylanHubbs If it was the second `while` that was giving you trouble you have to include the `timeRemaining()` function to get help on the issue. And `while` is fine, your implementation of it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `return` statement in the wrong place. Try this:

```
# This gets the robot unstuck if it is stalled
def unstuck():
    """ This gets the robot unstuck if it becomes stalled by hitting a wall """
    stalls = 0
    while timeRemaining(120):
        stallStatus = getStall()
        if(stallStatus == 1):
            backward(1,1)
            turnRight(1,1.7145)
            stalls = stalls + 1
        else:
            forward(1,1)
    stop()
    return stalls
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything works properly with your edit!